# Merge 1 list into another list based on the fixed position 2,15,16,25

Tags: c#

Request:
single-column content push after the 1st product card
2-column content push after the next 12 product cards
single-column content push after 8 product cards

Error:
But placement was missed while we adding more than 200 product

Have tried this

```
public List<ProductInfo> GetProductListDetails1(IEnumerable<IMasterProduct> cards, int? skipCount, int? takeCount, string productListId)
{
    var productListItem = this.SitecoreContext.GetItem<Models.IProductList>(productListId);
    List<Item> SingleList = productListItem.Item.GetChildren().Where(x => x.TemplateID.ToString() == "{BEDD19B0-0AA3-4AC8-A714-B92D23623FAA}")?.ToList();
    List<Item> DoubleList = productListItem.Item.GetChildren().Where(x => x.TemplateID.ToString() == "{93FCEC36-8E81-4852-A452-720B4076C2C5}")?.ToList();
    cards = cards?.Where(p => p != null).ToArray() ?? new IMasterProduct[0];

    List<ProductInfo> list = new List<ProductInfo>();

    List<string> productCards = new List<string>
    {
        "Product 1",
        "Product 2",
        "Product 3",
        // Add more product cards here
    };

    List<string> contentPushes = new List<string>
    {
        "Single-column content push",
        "Two-column content push",
        "Single-column content push",
        // Repeat as needed
    };

    int productIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Add a product card
        Console.WriteLine(productCards[productIndex]);

        // Check if it's time to add a content push
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contentPushes[0]); // Single-column content push
        }
        else if (i % 13 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contentPushes[1]); // Double-column content push
        }
        else if (i % 21 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contentPushes[2]); // Single-column content push
        }

        // Move to the next product card
        productIndex = (productIndex + 1) % productCards.Count;
    }

    return list;
}
```

What is expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a List<List> to create a two dimensional array.

Below is simple case of packing string P1 to P57 into four columns

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create a list of 57 items
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= 57; i++)
            {
                data.Add("P" + i);
            }
            List<List<string>> packedData = PackList(data, 4);
        }
        static List<List<string>> PackList(List<string> data, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            List<List<string>> packedData = new List<List<string>>();

            List<string> newRow = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                if(i % numberOfColumns == 0)
                {
                    if (i > 0) packedData.Add(newRow);
                    newRow = new List<string>();
                }
                newRow.Add(data[i]);
            }
            packedData.Add(newRow);
            return packedData;
        }
        
    }
}
```